# How to grant read-read/write access to specific UIDs from Firebase Auth and Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been struggling to grasp an understanding from recent researching of how to implement to grant different access levels to certain users in my system. I want to be able to grant one user read access and another with read/write referencing their uid. What work is required to implement this?

Do I need to restructure my DB and how are my JSON rules structured?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE - Implemented new rules and db structure**

Current DB reference for store 01 -

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stores").child("Store 01").child("Task List"); //Find the Task List table in database and making a reference.
```

**Updated rules structure to the following**

```
{
"rules": {

"stores": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid) || root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid))",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
  },

"readUsers": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": false   
},


"readWriteUsers": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": false   
}
```

}
}

**Updated DB structure to the following**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have some specific database nodes listing your users, as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "Store01": {
            ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid) || root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid))",
            ".write": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      },

    "readUsers": {
            ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write": false   
    },


    "readWriteUsers": {
            ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write": false   
    }

  }
}
```

However, with your data model, there will be a problem because you are creating multiple `stores` as database root nodes. Each time you create a new store you would need to update the security rules!

You need to create these stores in a parent node, e.g. `stores`. Therefore, with the new `readUsers` and `readWriteUsers` nodes, your database would look like the following:

```
- task-list-for-managers
   - stores
     - Store01
        - ....  
     - Store02
        - ....    
   - readUsers
     - WV0676TY67TY9: true   //user Id
     - PU8776TIU6543: true   
     - .....
   - readWriteUsers
     - BD563DHDV7669: true   //user Id
     - 87RSBE6383912: true   
     - .....
```

And the rules would be as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "stores": {
            ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid) || root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid))",
            ".write": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      },

    "readUsers": {
            ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write": false   
    },


    "readWriteUsers": {
            ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write": false   
    }

  }
}
```

Note that, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade), read and write Rules cascade:

> If a rule grants read or write permissions at a particular path, then
>   it also grants access to all child nodes under it.

Comment: Thanks Renaud this looks really viable with what I'm trying to do, I was finding it hard to understand the "Secure your data" doc in context of my own project.

Comment: I certainly will once I get it functioning @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask if you need more help!

Comment: I have implemented the above into my project however, I am unable to read any from my database from other read/readWrite uid. I have updated my post with my current structure.

Comment: Instead of storing the users as `uid: "WV02...."` you need to store them as `WV02....: true` for example. `root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)` means that the node `readUsers` needs to have a child with id equal to the user's `uid`.

Comment: I can achieve read access for a user now but I'm unable to get any read/write access for the other user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190030/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-alex-bingham).