# How to give read users some write access

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to give read-users the ability to edit/write some child nodes: See DB below (Status and Assigned-to). What I have done most recently is added the following rule:

Line 5  || root.child('writeByAll').hasChild(auth.uid))"

Unfortunately this gives the read user all write access, if this line is removed the user's write access is removed but I can't seem to get the correct result

I have taken a look at post [Firebase Database Rules for groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747851/firebase-database-rules-for-groups) but I can't put it into context.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, this is for a dissertation project. (Original rules here: [How to grant read-read/write access to specific UIDs from Firebase Auth and Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144125/how-to-grant-read-read-write-access-to-specific-uids-from-firebase-auth-and-data))

```
{
"rules": {

"stores": {
    ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid) || root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid))",
    ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('readWriteUsers').hasChild(auth.uid) || root.child('writeByAll').hasChild(auth.uid))",

"Status" : {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('writeByAll').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    ".write": "auth != null && root.child('writeByAll').hasChild(auth.uid)",
},
},


"readUsers": {
    ".read": "auth != null && root.child('readUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    ".write": false   
 },


"writeByAll": {
    ".read": "auth != null && root.child('writeByAll').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    ".write": false   
 }

    }
   }
```

[image]

Below is my edit task class -

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stores").child("Store 01").child("Task List"); // Reference Database


    spinnerType = findViewById(R.id.typeSpinner);
    status = findViewById(R.id.statusView);
    findViewById(R.id.saveTaskbtn).setOnClickListener(saveTask);

//        Retrieving data from background

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String passedType = intent.getStringExtra("passType");
    String passedStatus = intent.getStringExtra("passStatus")

    spinnerType.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)spinnerType.getAdapter()).getPosition(passedType));
    spinnerStatus.getAdapter()).getPosition(passedStatus));
    status.setText(passedStatus);


}//OnCreate

View.OnClickListener saveTask = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        final String key = intent.getStringExtra("passKey");


                DatabaseReference typeRef = ref.child("Type");
                DatabaseReference statusRef = ref.child("Status")

                String type = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String statusName = status.getText().toString();

                assignedRef.setValue(assignee);
                typeRef.setValue(type);
                statusRef.setValue(statusName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
```

Comment: There's quite a few rules and data here. Can you reduce it to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem? It'd also be really helpful to see the code (or a screenshot of the simulator) that is failing.

Comment: I've updated my post @FrankvanPuffelen however I found it difficult to condense my rules down without it not making sense, I have also provided my edit_task class  to give some context, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I scanned the code, but am having a hard time to see what is failing. Please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find out how (and why) to create a minimal repro. Some ideas: if the question is about writing, you should be able to reproduce the problem without code/rules/json related to reading. It also seems unlikely you need all the fields to reproduce the problem. As the linked page explains: start anew to reproduce the problem. At best you may find the problem yourself, at worst you'll have the minimum info we need to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ,nothing is actually failing in my code. I'm just unable to structure my rules to allow "ReadUsers" to be able to update some fields in the database. I have placed the "ReadUser" in another group called "WriteByAll". From my basic understanding, I have attempted to give this group write access to DB fields "Assigned to" and "Status" as seen in the rules structured above. Note: I have successfully created a read/write group and readonly group to utilise this code successfully. This is the next step.

Comment: @FrankvanPufflen, I've removed a number of field variables in my class to only show one that can should be editable by the read-user and another that they should only be able to read. I've updated the rules to represent that as well.

Comment: Sorry, I've honestly stared at this for minutes now, but can't figure out what you're trying to do. There is just too much context about your app that I don't get. I hope somebody else understands it better, but otherwise I still recommend the same: start with a blank slate and reproduce the problem with minimal code/json/rules.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your input